# Why "Content-Length: 0" in POST requests?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, http, web-applications, proxy

A customer sometimes sends POST requests with `Content-Length: 0` when submitting a form (10 to over 40 fields).

We tested it with different browsers and from different locations but couldn't reproduce the error. The customer is using Internet Explorer 7 and a proxy.

We asked them to let their system administrator see into the problem from their side. Running some tests without the proxy, etc..

In the meantime (half a year later and still no answer) I'm curious if somebody else knows of similar problems with a `Content-Length: 0` request. Maybe from inside some Windows network with a special proxy for big companies.

Is there a known problem with Internet Explorer 7? With a proxy system? The Windows network itself?

Google only showed something in the context of NTLM (and such) authentication, but we aren't using this in the web application. Maybe it's in the way the proxy operates in the customer's network with Windows logins? (I'm no Windows expert. Just guessing.)

I have no further information about the infrastructure.

**UPDATE:** In December 2010 it was possible to inform one administrator about this, incl. links from the answers here. Contact was because of another problem which was caused by the proxy, too. No feedback since then. And the error messages are still there. I'm laughing to prevent me from crying.

**UPDATE 2:** This problem exists since mid 2008. Every few months the customer is annoyed and wants it to be fixed ASAP. We send them all the old e-mails again and ask them to contact their administrators to either fix it or run some further tests. In December 2010 we were able to send some information to 1 administrator. No feedback. Problem isn't fixed and we don't know if they even tried. And in May 2011 the customer writes again and wants this to be fixed. The same person who has all the information since 2008.

Thanks for all the answers. You helped a lot of people, as I can see from some comments here. Too bad the real world is this grotesque for me.

**UPDATE 3:** May 2012 and I was wondering why we hadn't received another demand to fix this (see UPDATE 2). Looked into the error protocol, which only reports this single error every time it happened (about 15 a day). It stopped end of January 2012. Nobody said anything. They must have done something with their network. Everything is OK now. From summer 2008 to January 2012. Too bad I can't tell you what they have done.

**UPDATE 4:** September 2015. The website had to collect some data and deliver it to the main website of the customer. There was an API with an account. Whenever there was a problem they contacted us, even if the problem was clearly on the other side. For a few weeks now we can't send them the data. The account isn't available anymore. They had a relaunch and I can't find the pages anymore that used the data of our site. The bug report isn't answered and nobody complaint. I guess they just ended this project.

**UPDATE 5:** March 2017. The API stopped working in the summer of 2015. The customer seems to continue paying for the site and is still accessing it in February 2017. I'm guessing they use it as an archive. They don't create or update any data anymore so this bug probably won't reemerge after the mysterious fix of January 2012. But this would be someone else's problem. I'm leaving.

Comment: I suspect the proxy. My guess is that the browser actually doesn't send a Content-Length header, and that the proxy fills it in with the value it "sees": no value == 0.

Comment: What problems is the existence of this header causing you?

Comment: @Joel: It's not the header, it's the missing content. Empty body. The application expects some data and throws an error.

Comment: @stesch: Amazing! I just re-opened a bug report from our customer from 5 years ago. I read my ticket updates which lead me via google to your report :-) The setup you report is matching the one of my customer. The customer ran the same setup. IE7 behind a proxy. Now they are using IE8, but the error still occurs from time to time. The error seems to be bound to a specific form.I suspect the proxy to be the culprit. Do you remember which proxy was used at your customer ? I'm seeing "HTTP_VIA '1.1 LANPROXY'".Don't know what the actual proxy product is called. I can ask if someone is interested.

Comment: This registry key is solved this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41004109/129346

Comment: (Imagine this is in 3pt font) This exact issue can also happen if you, um, forget to give your form fields `name`s, and just give them `id`s instead.

Comment: @i336_ No, it can't. The data would always be missing.

Answer (score 46):

Internet Explorer does not send form fields if they are posted from an authenticated site (NTLM) to a non-authenticated site (anonymous).

This is feature for challange-response situations (NTLM- or Kerberos- secured web sites) where IE can expect that the first POST request immediately leads to an *HTTP 401 Authentication Required* response (which includes a challenge), and only the second POST request (which includes the response to the challange) will actually be accepted. In these situations IE does not upload the possibly large request body with the first request for performance reasons. Thanks to [EricLaw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328281/why-content-length-0-in-post-requests/630059?noredirect=1#comment24906051_630059) for posting that bit of information in the comments.

This behavior occurs every time an HTTP POST is made from a NTLM authenticated (i.e. Intranet) page to a non-authenticated (i.e. Internet) page, or if the non-authenticated page is part of a frameset, where the frameset page is authenticated.

The work-around is either to use a GET request as the form method, or to make sure the non-authenticated page is opened in a fresh tab/window (favorite/link target) without a partly authenticated frameset. As soon as the authentication model for the whole window is consistent, IE will start to send form contents again.

---

- Definitely related: http://www.websina.com/bugzero/kb/browser-ie.html
- Possibly related: [KB923155](https://web.archive.org/web/20130925033628/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/923155)
- **Full Explanation**: [IEInternals Blog – Challenge-Response Authentication and Zero-Length Posts](https://web.archive.org/web/20151109032611/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-post-bodies-are-zero-bytes-in-length-when-authentication-challenges-are-expected.aspx)

Comment: Frameset? This could be. The customer isn't very accessible, so it would be hard to ask. (They don't even care enough to ask their own IT, but care enough to complain from time to time.) But I can include a frame escape in the code and see if I get any more errors.

Comment: It might be that a frame-escape is not sufficient. IE is quite persistent in remembering that the window once *was* (at least partly) NTLM-authenticated. I look forward to hearing how it goes, though.

Comment: This is the most promising answer so far. I'm waiting until Friday, before the bounty ends. The last error was 6 minutes before I installed the frame escape.

Comment: The bounty system doesn't allow me to wait any longer. There are no errors so far, but I can't be sure until the customer uses these forms often enough. Statistically at least one error should have occurred since last Wednesday. But there was none.

Comment: I'll keep my fingers crossed for you. :-)

Comment: OK, the error still occurs. But the answer was good and could help if one could talk to this customer.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I hope you will find a workable solution, as I am still sure that this is the problem you are facing. Have you tried wrapping your form in an AJAX call to circumvent the IE form post mechanism? This would be the next thing I would try.

Comment: @Tomalak - thanks, I had this exact issue and it was reproduceable, so I could fix it...

Comment: The "security" claims in this answer are factually inaccurate. The behavior in question is explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-post-bodies-are-zero-bytes-in-length-when-authentication-challenges-are-expected.aspx

Comment: @EricLaw I've updated the answer with the information from your blog post. Thanks again.

Answer (score 15):

This is easy to reproduce with MS-IE and an NTLM authentication filter on server side. I have the same issue with JCIFS (1.2.*), struts 1.* and MS-IE 6/7 on XP-SP2. It was finally fixed. There are several workarounds to make it up.

1. change form method from POST (struts default setting) to GET. 
   For most pages with small sized forms, it works well. Unfortunately i have possibly more than 50 records to send in HTTP stream back to server side. IE has a GET URL limit 2038 Bytes (not parameter length, but the whole URL length). So this is a quick workaround but not applicable for me.
2. send a GET before POST action executing. 
   This was recommended in MS-KB. My project has many legacy procedures and i would not take the risk at the right time. I have never tried this because it still needs some extra authentication processing when GET is received by filter layer based on my understanding from MS-KB and I would not like to change the behavior with other browsers, e.g. Firefox, Opera.
3. detecting if POST was sent with zero content-length (you may get it from header properties hash structure with your framework). 
   If so, trigger an NTLM authentication cycle by get challenge code from DC or cache and expect an NTLM response. 
   When the NTLM type2 msg is received and the session is still valid, you don't really need to authenticate the user but just forward it to the expected action if POST content-length is not zero. BTW, this would increase the network traffics. So check your cache life time setting and SMB session soTimeOut configuration before applying the change plz.
   Or, more simple, you may just send a 401-unauthorized status to MS-IE and the browser shall send back POST request with data in reply.
4. MS-KB has provided a hot-fix with KB-923155 (I could not post more than one link because of a low reputation number :{ ) , but it seems not working. Would someone post a workable hot-fix here? Thanks :) Here is a link for reference, http://www.websina.com/bugzero/kb/browser-ie.html

Answer (score 6):

**There's a good chance the problem is that the proxy server in between implements HTTP 1.0.**

In HTTP 1.0 you must use the Content-Length header field: ([See section 10.4 here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#Content-Length))

> A valid Content-Length is required on
>   all HTTP/1.0 POST requests. An
>   HTTP/1.0 server should respond with a
>   400 (bad request) message if it cannot
>   determine the length of the request
>   message's content.

The request going into the proxy is HTTP 1.1 and therefore does not need to use the Content-Length header field.  The Content-Length header is usually used but not always.  See the following excerpt from the [HTTP 1.1 RFC S. 14.13](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13).

> Applications SHOULD use this field to
>   indicate the transfer-length of the
>   message-body, unless this is
>   prohibited by the rules in [section
>   4.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4).
>   Any Content-Length greater than or
>   equal to zero is a valid value.
>
> Section [4.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) describes how to determine
>   the length of a message-body if a
>   Content-Length is not given.

So the proxy server does not see the Content-Length header, which it assumes is absolutely needed in HTTP 1.0 if there is a body.  So it assumes 0 so that the request will eventually reach the server.     Remember the proxy doesn't know the rules of the HTTP 1.1 spec, so it doesn't know how to handle the situation when there is no Content-Length header.

Are you 100% sure your request is specifying the Content-Length header?  If it is using another means as defined in section 4.4 because it thinks the server is 1.1 (because it doesn't know about the 1.0 proxy in between) then you will have your described problem.

Perhaps you can use HTTP GET instead to bypass the problem.

Answer (score 6):

We have a customer on our system with exactly the same problem. We've pin pointed it down to the proxy/firewall. Microsoft's IAS. It's stripping the POST body and sending content-length: 0. Not a lot we can do to work around however, and down want to use GET requests as this exposes usernames/passwords etc on the URL string. There's nearly 7,000 users on our system and only one with the problem... also only one using Microsoft IAS, so it has to be this.

Comment: We have the exact same problem 3 years later with the same proxy product.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known problem for Internet explorer 6, but not for 7 that I know of.  You can install this fix for the IE6 [KB831167](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=254eb128-5053-48a7-8526-bd38215c74b2&displaylang=en) fix.

You can [read more about it here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v4r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.support.was.doc/html/Plug-in/1165399.html).

Some questions for you:

- Do you know which type of proxy?
- Do you know if there is an actual body sent in the request?
- Does it happen consistently every time? Or only sometimes?
- Is there any binary data sent in the request? Maybe the data starts with a \0 and the proxy has a bug with binary data.

Comment: The problem is, that I can't install anything. Difficult customer. and they are using IE7. They don't even contact their own IT department to try it without a proxy.

Comment: Type unknown. No body sent (when this problem occurs). Irregular. No binary.

Answer (score 2):

If the user is going through an ISA proxy that uses NTLM authentication, then it sounds like this issue, which has a solution provided (a patch to the ISA proxy)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942638
POST requests that do not have a POST body may be sent to a Web server that is published in ISA Server 2006

Answer (score 2):

I also had a problem where requests from a customer's IE 11 browser had `Content-Length: 0` and did not include the expected POST content. When the customer used Firefox, or Chrome the expected content was included in the request.

I worked out the cause was the customer was using a HTTP URL instead of a HTTPS URL (e.g. `http://...`, not `https://...`) and our application uses HSTS. It seems there might be a bug in IE 11 that when a request gets upgraded to HTTPS due to HSTS the request content gets lost.

Getting the customer to correct the URL to `https://...` resulted in the content being included in the POST request and resolved the problem.

I haven't investigated whether it is actually a bug in IE 11 any further at this stage.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!

I just spent the entire day chasing my tail looking at the NTLM optimisation red herring for this. It turns out it was a bug in IE11 all along. It also turns out that IE11 on Windows 10 seems to ignore the HSTS registry settings, so it still does this even when you tell it not to (unlike Windows 7), so we never noticed this until upgrading to Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure these requests are coming from a "customer"?

I've had this issue with bots before; they sometimes probe sites for "contact us" forms by sending blank POST requests based on the action URI in FORM tags they discover during crawling.

Comment: Every 0-POST error triggers an e-mail with user name and request header. I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

Presence and possible values of the ContentLength header in HTTP are described in the HTTP ( I assume 1/1) RFC:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13

> *In HTTP, it SHOULD be sent whenever the message's length can be determined prior to being transferred*

See also:

> *If a message is received with both a
>        Transfer-Encoding header field and a Content-Length header field,
>        the latter MUST be ignored.*
>   http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4

Maybe your message is carrying a Transfer-Encoding header?

Later edit: also please note "SHOULD" as used in the RFC is very important and not equivalent to "MUST":

> *3. SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there
>      may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a
>      particular item, but the full implications must be understood and
>      carefully weighed before choosing a different course.*
>   Ref: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt

Comment: No Transfer-Encoding. :-(

Sounded reasonable and I was constructing some further explanations in my head … but no Transfer-Encoding in the header.

Comment: This explains why it's there, though, even if the server is supposed to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

We had a customer using same website in anonymous and NTLM mode (on different ports). We found out that in our case the 401 was related to Riverbed Steelhead application used for http optimization. The first signal pointing us into that direction was a X-RBT-Optimized-By header. The issue was the Gratuitous 401 feature:

> This feature can be used with both per-request and per-connection
>   authentication but it‘s most effective when used with per-request
>   authentication. With per-request authentication, every request must be
>   authenticated against the server before the server would serve the
>   object to the client. However, most browsers do not cache the server‘s
>   response requiring authentication and hence it will waste one
>   round-trip for every GET request. With Gratuitous 401, the client-side
>   Steelhead appliance will cache the server response and when the client
>   sends the GET request without any authentication headers, it will
>   locally respond with a ―401 Unauthorized‖ message and therefore saving
>   a round trip. Note that the HTTP module does not participate in the
>   actual authentication itself. What the HTTP module does is to inform
>   the client that the server requires authentication without requiring
>   it to waste one round trip.

Answer (score 0):

Google also shows this as an IE (some versions, anyway) bug after an https connection hits the keepalive timeout and reconnects to the server.  The solution seems to be configuring the server to not use keepalive for IE under https.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's hotfix for [KB821814](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821814) can set Content-Length to 0:

> The hotfix that this article describes implements a code change in Wininet.dll to:
>
> - Detect the RESET condition on a POST request.
> - Save the data that is to be posted.
> - Retry the POST request with the content length set to 0. This prevents the reset from occurring and permits the authentication process to complete.
> - Retry the original POST request.

Answer (score 0):

`curl` sends `PUT/POST` requests with `Content-Length: 0` when configured to use HTTP proxy. It's trick to overcome required buffering in case of first unauthorized `PUT/POST` request to proxy. In case of `GET/HEAD` requests `curl` simply repeats the query. The scheme for `PUT/POST` is like:

1. Send first `PUT/POST` request with `Content-Length` set to 0.
2. Get answer. HTTP status code of 407 means we have to use proxy
   authorization. Prepare headers for proxy authentication for send request.
3. Send request again with filled headers for proxy authentication and real data to POST/PUT.