# Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call : encodedRequest cannot be empty

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, tomcat, single-sign-on, ntlm

The similar problem is described here: [GWT IllegalArgumentException: encodedRequest cannot be empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210926/gwt-illegalargumentexception-encodedrequest-cannot-be-empty)

My GWT application is deployed in Tomcat6, which is linked with Apache by using Coyote/JK2 connectors. For SSO I use the mod_auth_sspi/1.0.4.

When I use IE8, pages is not displayed, but for Firefox everything OK. In Tomcat logs I see the following:

```
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: encodedRequest cannot be empty
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:232)
    at org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.processCall(SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.java:32)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at gov.department.it.server.RequestInterceptorFilter.doFilter(RequestInterceptorFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:311)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:776)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:705)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:898)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

What have I tried so far:

1) Can't find the registry key `DisableNTLMPreAuth` (IMHO it's not the solution, because in my case IE 8 is actively used).

2) I have installed and configured the Native Windows Authentication Framework [WAFFLE](http://dblock.github.io/waffle/)

web.xml:

```
...
<filter>
    <filter-name>NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider/protocols</param-name>
        <param-value>NTLM</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
...
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/my-app/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
```

But it did not help.

3) In `worker.properties` I set `socket_keepalive=0`, but it did not help too -

```
worker.ajp13.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13.host=localhost
worker.ajp13.port=8009
worker.ajp13.lbfactor=50
worker.ajp13.cachesize=10
worker.ajp13.cache_timeout=600
worker.ajp13.socket_keepalive=0
worker.ajp13.socket_timeout=300
```

What else can I try to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have rediscovered the 7 year old [bug #1](http://sourceforge.net/p/mod-auth-sspi/bugs/) in `mod_auth_sspi` which has affected numerous projects, frustrated numerous developers, and caused uncountable wasted man-hours over the years. Yet it still stands unresolved because the maintainer [doesn't consider it a bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/mod-auth-sspi/bugs/1/?limit=10&page=2#1175). Nor has it been addressed by Microsoft for older browsers, because indications are that IE9 doesn't have this problem.

**Cause**

It is caused by IE trying to be 'smart' and sending a zero content-length POST (I named it `0POST` to try making it an indexable term to benefit those who rediscover it in the *next* 7 years.) with an NTLM auth header in anticipation of being challenged by the server. IE does this when it has been authenticated before in that protection space. So it knows that it will be challenged again. Sadly mod_auth_sspi is not as smart as IE, so bad things happen on the server side when a 0POST arrives and it is let through to the apps without being challenged. Except that sometimes this can happen even for unprotected areas, if they are under an area that requires authentication.
Other browsers don't pretend to be as smart as IE and don't try to save a few bytes on the first round trip for "performance", so they don't run into this problem. Here is [Microsoft's explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-post-bodies-are-zero-bytes-in-length-when-authentication-challenges-are-expected.aspx) of this behavior.

**Horrible Workaround**

In Apache httpd.conf set

```
SSPIPerRequestAuth On
```

This is equivalent to the [DisableNTLMPreAuth](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251404) IE client-side fix you mentioned, which is impractical for a large user group. Plus it amounts to crippling all non-Apache apps also, which may be capable of handling a 0POST. There are literally NO examples of this setting being discussed or its side effects explained on the web, so I am including this [only link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/107730-windows-7-ntlm-pre-auth-problem-with-spnego) I found that sheds some light on it. Anyway, making one server side change seems to be the lesser of the two evils. Although now, by changing the server config, you have crippled all other innocent browsers visiting this site as well.

The problem with this workaround is that it forces EVERY request to perform an SSPI handshake which results in a lot of extra 401 traffic and can affect performance. For performance, NTLM authentication is treated as 'session-based' not 'request-based' which means that the handshake occurs only at the start of the session. When using this setting, you should also set filters to prevent your log filling up with 401s. Also note that this requires KeepAlive to be turned on.

I am not sure your setup is the same as the one described in the WAFFLE fix; were they using Apache like you? I think WAFFLE applies to Tomcat, whereas you have Apache in front, so Apache is handling authentication. You might consider using that setup instead of Apache. If you can use that setup, it may be a better option than this workaround because WAFFLE has explicitly accounted for 0POST and [can handle it](http://waffle.codeplex.com/discussions/270109). The author had [also discovered this](http://code.dblock.org/ntlm-please-show-id-with-every-post) gem while working with GWT like you.

Interestingly, for jcifs, [a fix for this very issue was posted](http://lists.samba.org/archive/jcifs/2004-December/004459.html) *9 Years ago*. The author also provided an [excellent explanation](http://lists.samba.org/archive/jcifs/2006-September/006554.html) later:

> The code in the filter examines all HTTP POST requests and determines
>   if they contain an NTLM type 1 message.  If the request contains an
>   NTLM type 1 message, **the filter responds with a dummy type 2 message
>   to entertain IE's desire to re-negotiate NTLM prior to submitting any
>   POST data.**  The browser should then respond with an NTLM type 3
>   message along with the post data which the filter should then allow to
>   chain to the rest of the web application.

A [simple patch](http://sourceforge.net/p/mod-auth-sspi/patches/6/) was also created for mod_auth_sspi 5 years ago, if you are interested. [See diff](https://bitbucket.org/jamesvl/mod_auth_sspi/commits/9ce2bd078485519f2f6a13fe6bba34ba) in the author's own repo. I am not sure if I agree with that approach though. It tries to detect IE/0POST, whereas I think the right fix should be to detect if the client is requesting auth with a NTLM Type 1 header, as in the jcifs filter. (Type 1 simply means that it is the first message of the handshake)

I wonder if anyone has used alternatives to `mod_auth_sspi` like `mod_auth_ntlm_winbind` and if they don't exhibit this behavior. If you have, please leave a comment. We already know WAFFLE works, but it is not a mod_auth_sspi replacement.

One alternative is to forget NTLM and use Kerberos, ([`mod_auth_kerb`](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/)) but many people find that too complicated to setup. IE will behave this way on any challenge-response scheme, so odds are that kerb auth could run into the same problem, since a similar 401 sequence happens in both cases. But being a different module, its possible it is capable of handling this.

Lastly, I should mention that there is yet another issue that this per-request auth workaround doesn't seem to fix. I haven't seen it discussed anywhere, but I have found that sometimes after the 0POST, the server waits for a very long time before it responds with the final 200 response with the results of the (proper) POST. This long delay happens only in the end though, NOT immediately in response to the 0POST. That goes fine, and the handshake completes, but the server doesn't respond until after a long wait which I have noticed is suspiciously close to 90 seconds, like some sort of timeout. The practical result of this is that when users log in, IE8 will sometimes hang for 90sec waiting for server response. I thought the `KeepAlive` might be causing it, but it is not even explicitly defined in my config, so I assume it is at the 15sec Apache default. But I am sure this is related to the 0POST, because it happens only right after a successful 0POST auth handshake. Our server is in a separate (2-way) trusted domain across a firewall, so maybe that has something to do with it.

**Diverse Examples of This Issue**

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/NullPointerException+when+Authenticating+from+IE
- http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/2696
- http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/4560
- https://drupal.org/node/82530
- http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3087425.htm
- [Why "Content-Length: 0" in POST requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328281/why-content-length-0-in-post-requests)
- https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1087

The most hilarious example is how IE's smartness affected Microsoft's own products! They themselves couldn't understand how to deal with IE's behavior, causing a bug in ISA Server 2006.

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942638

Comment: "because indications are that IE9 doesn't have this problem" - and now we have 2015, and IE11 apparently still does that....