# Have you ever seen a proxy removing POST request values?

Tags: ajax, proxy

I have come acrooss a very strange problem.

I use a POST request for asynchronous data transfer via XMLHHTPRequest. Some clients behind a proxy seem to send the request, but all POST data seems lost. After testing a few days I could not reproduce this on my local system. Could a proxy remove POST data, when there is no change in it?

Comment: I have seen this, incoming request has Content-Length: 0. Is this still a problem for you, or did you manage to fix it? Also see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328281/why-content-length-0-in-post-requests)

Comment: After many weeks of logging problematic requests we could identify a bunch of IE-Plugins that actually trigger a second empty request to the same service endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen them (and Firebug) strip headers, but never POST content. Does a normal POST request work from behind that proxy? Eg a web page.

Comment: Yes everything else of the app behaves normal (whole Administration panel is used). Just one post Request. I am not behind the proxy, so I was just thinking that maybe this is a possible explanation.