# JS POST request via form.submit() differs from click one

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, post, request

I need to submit post method form using javascript, this is the form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <p>
    <input class="button white bigwidth" type="submit" name="imgContinue" value="Continue to image ... ">
  </p>
</form>
```

and this is how I try to send it via JS:

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
if(form.length != 0) {
  form[0].submit();
}
```

But it doesn't work the same way as clicking on the button (I checked there is just a jquery click handlers attached)

test page: http://imgmoney.com/img-515f13c1bb27c.html

Any suggestions how to automaticly send the form the same way as user mouse click does it?

Request via form.submit()

```
POST http://imgmoney.com/img-515f13c1bb27c.html HTTP/1.1
Host: imgmoney.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://imgmoney.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://imgmoney.com/img-515f13c1bb27c.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: PHPSESSID=b9ef96omfovrk66op827t1sim3; HstCfa2204047=1374076305244; HstCmu2204047=1374076305244; Cls_weather=low%7Bundefined%7Dhigh%7Bundefined%7Dicon%7Bundefined%7Dcondition%7Bundefined%7Dbase%7Bhttp%3A//www.google.com%7Dsug_unit%7BC%7Dcity%7BSaint%20Petersburg%7Dcountry%7BRU%7D; __atuvc=2%7C29; noadvtday=0; ao_s=7; HstCla2204047=1374076527809; HstPn2204047=7; HstPt2204047=7; HstCnv2204047=1; HstCns2204047=1; MLRV_72204047=1374076528372; MLR72204047=1374076518000; __utma=24314786.908711371.1374076306.1374076306.1374076306.1; __utmb=24314786.7.10.1374076306; __utmc=24314786; __utmz=24314786.1374076306.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

and via mouse click by user

```
POST http://imgmoney.com/img-515f13c1bb27c.html HTTP/1.1
Host: imgmoney.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 34
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://imgmoney.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://imgmoney.com/img-515f13c1bb27c.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: PHPSESSID=b9ef96omfovrk66op827t1sim3; HstCfa2204047=1374076305244; HstCmu2204047=1374076305244; Cls_weather=low%7Bundefined%7Dhigh%7Bundefined%7Dicon%7Bundefined%7Dcondition%7Bundefined%7Dbase%7Bhttp%3A//www.google.com%7Dsug_unit%7BC%7Dcity%7BSaint%20Petersburg%7Dcountry%7BRU%7D; __atuvc=2%7C29; noadvtday=0; ao_s=8; HstCla2204047=1374076561596; HstPn2204047=8; HstPt2204047=8; HstCnv2204047=1; HstCns2204047=1; __utma=24314786.908711371.1374076306.1374076306.1374076306.1; __utmb=24314786.8.10.1374076306; __utmc=24314786; __utmz=24314786.1374076306.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); MLRV_72204047=1374076562369; MLR72204047=1374076555000

imgContinue=Continue+to+image+...+
```

And I need to do last request above via JS, any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think this is the result of the manual submission using js, it seems that it is your condition that triggers the submit is the cause of all that. in addition, form.length checks the number of forms you have in the page not the contents. so you are submitting an empty form since you have at least one form all the time and 1!=0.

Comment: what manual submission? what condition? I just wrote results from my tests, one at top from js code executed with form.submit() and second from my hand clicking the submit button with mouse, I just need to get same result with JS not with hand. And length chech is there just not to trigger an error if no form is present on page (damn, I got answer about my additional code which has nothing to do with the problem again not the problem itself =_=) - So how do I submit not an empty form but same as manual-click one?

Comment: can you show where you are triggering that chunk of code in the question from ? because I believe you are submitting an empty form.

Comment: sure I can, I do it at the test page url posted in Original Post. via chrome console I trigger form.submit();

Comment: please add the full js code to your question ..

Comment: js code in my question is full, enter it into console and it would fully work (but not as expected)

Comment: I know how to trigger it from the console. but I want to read your code to debug it!

Comment: go ahead with reading, I don't mind, as I said my full code is in my question at top of this page but if you want it right here I'll copy it again (hope this is what you ment): 
`var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
if(form.length != 0) {
  form[0].submit();
}`

Comment: you are funny :) , read this while I'm reading it, seems related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328281/why-content-length-0-in-post-requests

Comment: I'm just not getting what you write, partially. So this is a bug in Chrome simular to one in IE?

Comment: sorry, I never encountered this problem before ,, I'll update you when I know something regarding that ..