# Apache web server sending 400 response

Tags: apache, ntlm, bad-request

We have configured NTLM authentication using SSPI on apache due to which the authentication is three steps, where there are two 401 responses followed by 201/200 response.

Now in IE browser, this breaks because of - [Why "Content-Length: 0" in POST requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328281/why-content-length-0-in-post-requests)

Apache web server sends a 400 bad request response due to empty post request due to which POST on the server breaks.

How can I configure Apache to not treat this as 400 BAD request and process it normally?